# Python / Корректно округлить цифры до целых чисел

Tags: python, numpy

В датасете есть столбик с оценками фильмов в формате float: 8.5, 8.6, 9.1, 7.9, 7.4 и т.п. Максимальное значение оценки - 9.5, минимальное - 4.1.

Задача - присвоить данным числам переменные в новом столбце; к примеру, оценка от 4.0 до 4.9 - "Плохо", от 5.0 до 6.9 - "Посредственно" и т.п.

Проблема в том, что написанная функция для создания указанных категорий отрабатывает некорректно, присваивая всем позициям "Отлично":

```
def score_funct(score):
if score in np.arange(4.0, 5.0, 0.1):
        return 'Плохо'
    elif score in np.arange(5.0, 7.0, 0.1):
        return 'Посредственно'
    elif score in np.arange(7.0, 9.0, 0.1):
        return 'Хорошо'
    else:
        return 'Отлично'
```

При помощи round() округление некоторых цифр идёт всё время в меньшую сторону; например, 8.5 округляется как 8.

Модуль Decimal также не помогает - округляет только до десятых.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть какой-либо способ округлить корректно значения (то есть < 4.5 как 4 и >= 4.5 как 5) или учесть эти условия в функции?

Comment: сравнение вещественных чисел на равенство - еще то занятие. а почему не `4 <= score < 5`

Comment: Зачем здесь numpy вообще?

Answer (score 2):

C numpy удобно использовать numpy.select

```
import numpy as np

scores = np.array([4.7, 6.2, 8.1, 9.5])
cond = [9 <= scores, 7 <= scores, 5 <= scores, ]
marks = ['Отлично', 'Хорошо', 'Посредственно', ]
new_scores = np.select(cond, marks, default='Плохо')
print(new_scores)  
#['Плохо' 'Посредственно' 'Хорошо' 'Отлично']
```

Comment: Кстати, отличный вариант, не знал про такой. Только условия сами написаны так, что не сразу поймёшь, понятней было бы `scores > 9` и т.д.

Comment: это может быть, главное в правильном порядке - первое выполнившееся берется :)

Comment: @CrazyElf а вообще, это у меня от питоновского  1<  x < 5 пошло - писать в порядке возрастания :)

Comment: Ну двойное условие - это всё-таки другой случай )

Comment: Граничные условия не подходят по условию 5.0 Плохо, 7.0 Посредственно, 9.0 Хорошо

Comment: @СергейКох так и есть. не?

Comment: "от 5.0 до 6.9 - "Посредственно""

Comment: поменял на `<=`

Answer (score 2):

Решение с `np.digitize()`

**Вариант с функцией**

```
import random

def score_funct(score):
    return {0: 'Плохо', 1: 'Посредственно', 2: 'Хорошо', 3: 'Отлично'}[
        np.digitize(np.array([score]), np.array([5, 7, 9, 10]))[0]]

for _ in range(10):
    score = random.random() * 6 + 4
    print(f'{score:0.1f} - это {score_funct(score)}')
```

```
4.1 - это Плохо
8.8 - это Хорошо
8.6 - это Хорошо
9.0 - это Хорошо
5.8 - это Посредственно
4.2 - это Плохо
7.1 - это Хорошо
6.1 - это Посредственно
9.3 - это Отлично
7.8 - это Хорошо
```

**Вариант без функции**

```
scores = np.array([4, 8.5, 8.6, 9.1, 7.9, 7.4])
bins = np.array([5, 7, 9, 10])
d = {0: 'Плохо', 1: 'Посредственно', 2: 'Хорошо', 3: 'Отлично'}
result = np.array([d[x] for x in np.digitize(scores, bins)])
print(result)
```

```
['Плохо' 'Хорошо' 'Хорошо' 'Отлично' 'Хорошо' 'Хорошо']
```

Comment: Либо ставьте параметр `right=True` либо меняйте значения. "4.9 - это Посредственно" получается по вашему конфигу. Всегда тестируйте в том числе и на граничных значениях.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо, учёл

Comment: А зачем словарь? Обычный список подойдет, все равно, индексы числовые

Answer (score 0):

Если уж речь за `Numpy`, то используйте `np.where`:

```
import numpy

def score_funct(score):
    return np.where(score < 5.0, 'Плохо',
              np.where(score < 7.0, 'Посредственно',
                  np.where(score < 9.0, 'Хорошо',
                      'Отлично')))
    
assert score_funct(4.5) == 'Плохо'
assert score_funct(5.0) == 'Посредственно'
assert score_funct(7.0) == 'Хорошо'
assert score_funct(np.Inf) == 'Отлично'
```

`in range` и `in np.arange` нормально работают только для целых чисел, для чисел с плавающей точкой это работает только частично из-за погрешностей представления чисел с плавающей точкой.